# Check a valeur with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-traffic

I want to verify that i have a trafic in my box. So i want to check that "Total" is different de 0 but i fail.

http://clip2net.com/s/54bx8J

HTML code :

```
<span>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="left">Upload</td>
<td class="right">276 KB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left">Download</td>
<td class="right">661 KB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left">Total</td>
<td class="right">937 KB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left">Duration</td>
<td class="right">5min19s</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
```

And my script :

```
  WebElement data = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='right' and text()[contains(., 'Download')]/td[2]")));
         System.out.println(data);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

assertTrue(data != null);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to print the WebElement.  Instead, try to access its data by calling getAttribute or getText, depending on the type of element you are selecting.

See http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html for the WebElement spec.

Also, it would be helpful if you post the html source that you are trying to select/parse.

Comment: Thanks for your help
T want to check that "Total" is different to 0

<td class="right">937 KB</td>

Comment: calling getText() on your WebElement should return a String with "937 KB"

Comment: I just used getText() it's a good idea but i have a problem to récuperate the number (927 ) and check which it's different to 0.
 String data = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='right' and text()[contains(., 'Download')]/td[2]"))).getText();
       System.out.println(data);

Comment: once you have the value, all you need to do is parse the integer out of the string.  For ideas on how to do that, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java

Comment: I managed to retrieve the value, but I want to remove the 'MB' but substring () to remove it before it except that I want to delete the following numbers